# Web application Load Tests: What metrics to look at?

Tags: load-testing, performancecounter, perfmon

During a stress/load test of a ASP.NET app hosted in IIS, what should I be monitoring on the app server?

For example, the built in utility performance monitor in windows has a huge list of counters that I can monitor. But, I don't even know what half of these counters actually mean? I know I want to look at things like memory, processor, network....but it is pretty general.

How can I successfully find a problem area?

What counters some of you guys have used in the past?

Answer (score 5):

These metrics we watch to determine if requests are being serviced promptly and the volume is scaling linearly with the applied load:

- Queued Requests
- Current Requests
- Requests Executing
- Requests Succeeded
- Requests/sec

We will also watch these to look for application problems

- Errors/sec
- Unhandled Execution Errors/sec

To monitor the VM memory, we look at:

- CLR Heap Size
- CLR Generation 0, 1 & 2 Garbage collections
- CLR Percent Time in GC

For locking conditions, we watch:

- CLR Lock Contentions
- CLR Lock Contention/sec
- CLR Lock Contention Queue Length

Depending on the application we might look at others, like thread counts, but the above are the ones we look at most frequently.